# If $G$ is a locally cyclic group , then is $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, locally-cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a [locally cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group) group, then is it true that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is abelian ? I know that $G$ has to be abelian but I cannot decide for $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @user1952009 Where did you get the tensor product from? That is just isomorphic to the integers anyway. And no, it needs not be.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I meant $\times$. Why no ?

Comment: Presumably you can classify torsionfree $G$ with sets of primes and torsion $G$ with supernatural numbers.

Comment: @user1952009 That doesn't include $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$ for instance. And also $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ are not locally cyclic either.

Comment: It seems $\operatorname{End}G$ is a *commutative* ring. This implies  $\operatorname{Aut}G$ is abelian. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group).

Comment: @user1952009 $\Bbb Z[1/p]$ is the subring of $\Bbb Q$ comprised of all numbers that are expressible as a polynomial of $1/p$ with integer coefficient. Thus, its underlying additive group is all rational numbers with only powers of $p$ in their denominator. Then we take the quotient group mod $\Bbb Z$. This group is isomorphic to the group of all roots of unity with $p$-power order. It goes by the name Prufer $p$-group.

Comment: @arctictern you can write $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ as a limit of a sequence of groups, can you do the same for any locally cyclic group ?

Comment: Yes, every locally cyclic group is a countable union of its cyclic subgroups ordered linearly by inclusion.

Comment: @arctictern then you can use this classification of $G$ for classifying $Aut(G)$ ?

Comment: I assume so. That was the gist of my first comment above.

Comment: it reduces to showing $ \sigma \in Aut(G)$ is also $\in Aut(C)$ for any cyclic subgroup $C$ ? @arctictern

Comment: @arctictern : could you please elaborate why is that every locally cyclic group is a countable union of its cyclic subgroups ordered linearly by inclusion ?

Comment: @user1952009 : okay but what are these $H_n$ ;s ? that is my question that how to find those subgroups ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there's a nice way to do this.  Here's a not nice way.

Start with the observations 1) a locally cyclic group is either torsion or torsion free, and 2) every automorphism of a group lifts to an automorphism of its injective hull.  The point of 2) is that it means we can get our result by proving automorphism groups of injective hulls of locally cyclic groups are abelian.

Consider the torsion-free case.  Then $G$ embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is a nice argument and not difficult: pick $g \in G\setminus \{e\}$ and map it to 1, then for any $h \in G$ we have $nh=mg$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ by local cyclicity so map $h\mapsto m/n$, the details are given here http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_definitions_of_locally_cyclic_aperiodic_group). Its injective hull is then $\mathbb{Q}$, and so its automorphism group $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is abelian.

Now let $G$ be torsion. Then $G$ is a direct product of locally cyclic $p$-groups, one for each prime $p$ (contained in http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_definitions_of_locally_cyclic_periodic_group).  Its injective hull is then a restricted direct product of Prüfer groups $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, at most one for each prime.  The automorphism group of the injective hull is the product of the automorphism groups of the factors, which are the invertible $p$-adic integers, so abelian.

This problem is Exercise 113.2 p.254 in Fuchs' *Infinite Abelian Groups* vol. 2.

Comment: don't know why it is not nice. the non-trivial part is proving a torsion-free locally cyclic group is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$